# dpkg: error processing package libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64 (--configure):

Tags: apt, dpkg, 22.04, amdgpu

I had current Ubuntu on PC with AMD and then I transferred it to a PC with Intel. Today I erased something and it showed me this error after `apt-get update/upgrade`:

```
dpkg: error processing package libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64 (--configure):
```

When I restarted the PC, Ubuntu was broken and I saw only a black screen. I tried recovery mode etc, nothing works.

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the AMD GPU drivers, which prevents the OS to boot the graphical user interface. But the OS still works from the terminal. The solution is to:

1. Switch to TTY2 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>).
2. Login with username and password.
3. Run:

   ```
   /usr/bin/amdgpu-uninstall
   ```
4. Return to TTY1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).